# Plotting with if Statements in tkinter, not executing

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, tkinter

I have this code that analyzes which deliveries were late, either by a specific material number, or it can show which deliveries were late for all material numbers. From there I categorized the "lateness" by early deliveries, on time, and late, and then want to graph these results. This code worked fine without the GUI application part of it (tkinter), Now when I try to produce a graph, and want to specify if I want all the materials to be included, vs a specific material, nothing happens when I click the button to execute my code. I believe it has to do with the radiobutton and how I am setting the values that eventually produce the graph in the if statement; any suggestions on how I should go about the logic for that portion of the code?    I want to be able for this application to produce a bar graph of the categories I have listed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import*





master = Tk()


label2= Label(master, text='Start Year')
label2.grid(row=4, column=0)

label3= Label(master, text='End Year')
label3.grid(row=5, column=0)

label4= Label(master, text='Material')
label4.grid(row=6, column=0)




textBox = Text(master, height=1, width=10, font=('Consolas', 9))
textBox.grid(row=4, column=1)

textBox2 = Text(master, height=1, width=10, font=('Consolas', 9))
textBox2.grid(row=5, column=1)

textBox3 = Text(master, height=1, width=10, font=('Consolas', 9))
textBox3.grid(row=6, column=1)


All = StringVar()
All.set(1)

Alll = Radiobutton(master, text="All", variable=All, value=2)
Alll.grid(row=7, column=0)


Material = Radiobutton(master, text="Material", variable=All, value=1)
Material.grid(row=8, column=0)





def retrieve_input():
    StartYear = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c") 
    EndYear = textBox2.get("1.0","end-1c") 
    Materiall = textBox3.get("1.0","end-1c") 

    Material= 'Material'
    DELIVERY_DATE = 'Delivery Date'
    DESIRED_DATE = 'source desired delivery date'
    DELAYED_DAYS = 'Delayed Days'





    df = pd.read_csv('otdo.csv')

    df['Delivery Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delivery Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
    df['source desired delivery date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['source desired delivery date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')


    late_threshold = pd.Timedelta(days=0)
    late_threshold2 = pd.Timedelta(days=10)

    df[DELIVERY_DATE] = pd.to_datetime(df[DELIVERY_DATE])
    df[DESIRED_DATE] = pd.to_datetime(df[DESIRED_DATE])
    df[DELAYED_DAYS] = df[DELIVERY_DATE] - df[DESIRED_DATE]


    df2 = df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year >= int(StartYear)) & (df['Delivery Date'].dt.year <= int(EndYear))]




    df3 = df2[ df2[DELAYED_DAYS] > late_threshold] 
    df3 =  df3[late_threshold2 > df3[DELAYED_DAYS]]
    df3 = df3.loc[df['Material'].str.contains('1005459', na=False)]




    df4 = df2[ df2[DELAYED_DAYS] > late_threshold2] 
    df4 = df4.loc[df['Material'].str.contains('1005459', na=False)]



    df5 = df2[df2[DELAYED_DAYS] <= late_threshold] 
    df5 = df5.loc[df['Material'].str.contains('1005459', na=False)]



    df6 = df2.loc[df['Material'].str.contains('1005459', na=False)]





    df7 = df2[ df2[DELAYED_DAYS] > late_threshold] 
    df7 =  df7[late_threshold2 > df7[DELAYED_DAYS]]



    df8 = df2[ df2[DELAYED_DAYS] > late_threshold2] 


    df9 = df2[df2[DELAYED_DAYS] <= late_threshold] 



    zero3 = df4.count() 
    zero4 = df5.count() 
    zero5 = df7.count()
    zero6 = df8.count()
    zero7 = df9.count() 


    if All == 1:

        objects = ('1', '2', '3')
        y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
        values = [zero3.Material, zero4.Material, zero5.Material]

        plt.bar(y_pos, values, align='center', alpha=0.2)
        plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)

        plt.show()

    if All == 2:

        objects = ('1', '2', '3')
        y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
        values = [zero5.Material, zero6.Material, zero7.Material]

        plt.bar(y_pos, values, align='center', alpha=0.2)
        plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)

        plt.show()


button1 = Button(master,text="Show Values", command=lambda: retrieve_input())
button1.grid(row=13, column=1)



mainloop( )
```

csv file:

[image]

Gui:

[image]

Graph produced ( without the tkinter portion)

[image]

Sample data:

```
 Material    Delivery Date   source desired delivery date

3334678 12/31/2014  12/31/2014
233433  12/31/2014  12/31/2014
3434343 1/5/2015    1/6/2015
3334567 1/5/2015    1/5/2015
546456  2/11/2015   2/10/2015
221295  4/10/2015   4/10/2015
20065316    2/17/2015   2/17/2015
10011155    1/5/2015    1/5/2015
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the function is being called? Have you verified that the values of the variables it is using are what you assume they are? Are you absolutely certain that `All` is set to the integer `1` or `2`, or could it possibly be something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley That is what I am unsure about, in the radiobutton I set number values to Alll and Material, so that in the if statement, it can produce the graphs accordingly, however although I thought this logic made sense, I suppose the code is not executing how I think it should be.

Comment: So, add some debug statements. I recommend starting with `print(All)`. My guess is that you'll see something you don't expect. You should be doing this sort of debugging instead of asking us to do it for you.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes when I print(All.get()) I am getting the value 1, but I have specified if All == 1, then the graph should produce, correct?

Comment: _"I have specified if All == 1, then the graph should produce, correct?"_ - no, that is not correct. `All` does not equal the integer 1. `All` is an object. Like I suggested earlier, try `print(All)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay yes when I did try to print(All) if it was outside of the if statement, it simply printed PY_VAR0, if I print inside the if statement, nothing prints

Comment: @BryanOakley I understand that All is being equal to PY_VAR0, but not really sure why? Would you be able to explain this concept to me

Comment: @MichaelNorman Because you did `All = Stringvar()`

Comment: @Goyo Ahhh I see, I thought you had to always set that to SrtingVar(), I changed it to IntVar now and am met with the same results?

Comment: @MichaelNorman A `IntVar` is neither an `int` and comparing it to an `int` will always return `False`.

Comment: @Goyo Okay, I would think maybe I would have to use a BooleanVar then?? Or how would you recommend going about it.

Comment: @MichaelNorman I am wondering why you printed `All.get()` when Bryan asked tiy to print `All`.

Comment: @Goyo I did print All after that, I inititally did that because I was getting PY_VAR0 so I thought I had to use the get function( not sure what my logic for that was) Regardless, I did print All and simply got PY_VAR0 if it is outside of the if statement, nothing prints when it is in the if statement